# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Результатом станет ощутимый вклад в защиту окружающей среды, какой - мы узнаем на последнем этапе конкурса.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно. Ни убавить, ни прибавить.

Тире после "какой" - пропущено то ли "результат", то ли "вклад".

Можно ещё так объяснить тире: какой именно ("именно" опущено).

Возникает двусмысленность: "какой" можно согласовать и со средой, но наше дело - знаки. А они на месте.

Запятая разделяет два предложения:

*вклад станет результатом*

и

*мы узнаем.*

Comment: "Какой" должно быть согласовано по падежу: вклад - какой, результатом - каким (каким он будет - мы узнаем...).

Comment: М_Г, а как вы вообще эту фразу понимаете? По-моему её ни пунктуацией, ни косметической правкой (наподобие предложенной вами) не сделаешь понятнее. Я сейчас попытаюсь сформулировать свои сомнения в посте-ответе, но если вы раскоете свое понимание до того, бужет даже лучше.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такое ощущение, что фраза нуждается в достаточно серьезно переделке.
И дело не только и даже не столько в отмеченной двусмысленности, сколько в том, что без контекста смысл вообще не очень понятен, хотя и контекст вряд ли спасет.
В такой ситуации, когда не явен смысл, а из-за него и предполагаемый синтаксис, ставить вопрос о пунктуации, боюсь, не будет правильным.

Итак, можно предположить, что идет некий конкурс. И результатом (чего? конкурса?) станет некий вклад в защиту среды. ***Результатом конкурса - вклад???*** Увидеть в этом какой-то смысл можно разве что при хорошо развитой фантазии. Ну типа такого, что конкурс этот есть конкурс проектов защиты ОС. И результатом его почему-то станет не объявление победителей, а вклад. Но даже это за уши притянутое объяснение не выдерживает убийственного для понимания утверждения, что вклад этот еще никому и не известен до последнего этапа. А на последнем этапе его, вклад, мы почему-то узнаем. Вот так вот, вдруг. Возьмем и узнаем. Не победителей даже, а именно вклад.

Простите, это никакими запятыми не лечится. Делайте фразу понятнее и адекватнее...